# Glad or Nice to meet you?

Tags: greetings

Is there any difference between both expressions?

> **Nice** to meet you.

and

> **Glad** to meet you.

If yes, when or why use each one? Also, there are some variations as

> Nice to **see** you

or

> Nice to **found** you.

This rule apply to this greetings too?

Comment: [*Nice to meet you* is more common.](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=33057035)

Comment: [*Nice to meet you* versus *Glad to meet you* per mil in GloWbE](http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=33057214)

Comment: Very useful the [GloWbE](http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Nice to meet you.

This is short for *it is nice to meet you*.

> Glad to meet you.

This is short for *I am glad to meet you*.

Generally, they mean the same thing. When meeting someone (usually, for the first time), it is a positive experience. As such, *I am glad* has a bit more of a personal touch, I think: you actually refer to a personal emotion of being glad, whereas *it is nice* is more of  a general observation. The difference is subtle, though, and probably most people might not notice it. Compare for instance these two sentences:

> It's nice weather today.
>   I like the weather today.

They roughly mean the same thing, but the second one is more personal. (And of course, if I like weather that is not usually considered nice, they *may* mean something different.)

> Nice to see you.

Short for *it is nice to see you*, you use this when you meet someone you already know; as a rule of thumb, use *meet* when you meet someone for the first time, use *see* when you are acquainted with them.

> Nice to found you.

This sentence is grammatical, but it means you enjoy creating someone. If you mean you are happy about *finding* someone, make sure you use the verb *find*, not the verb [*found*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/found).

> Nice to find you here!
>   Glad that I found you!

These are both correct uses of *find*, and express happiness about having encountered someone (at this specific location).

*Glad to* is followed by an *infinitive*, so *glad to found you* would refer to the verb *found* as we see it in the *foundation* of a company, *the Founding Fathers* and the *founder* of a city. The man who founded a city is not the same as one that found it!

Answer (score 2):

*Nice* and *Glad* **in this context** mean the same thing - meeting someone, you are delightful, happy or feel happy/pleasure.

The expression *Nice to see you* is used when you see someone after a long time or out of your expectation. Say, you meet Mike after 4 years or at party, you did not expect Mike to be there.

Also, nice/glad to *meet* you talks about *meeting* someone and is **generally** used at the first encounter. On the other hand, nice/glad to *see* you is normally used when you are already acquainted with someone but feel a *bit* surprising (happy) *looking* at them at the place.

*Nice to found you* does not fit in this context (and yes, to+found is weird here). It may mean the person was missing!

Comment: This was a good answer until your explanation of _Nice to found you_. oerkelens gets that part right.

Comment: @200_success No worries. The context is *greeting* someone and I did not want to stretch my answer discovering all possibilities of using an English word. We use the same word in more than a dozen way, don't we?

Comment: @MaulikV: _found_ in that sentence cannot be read as a grammatical form of the verb _find_...

Comment: @oerkelens That's why I edited it with *to+found*.

Comment: But "nice to find you here" is perfectly fine! _nice to found_ just has nothing to do with finding someone or someone that was missing. "It may mean the person was missing"? No, it may not mean that, not in English! _Nice to found you_ does not contains anything to do with finding people.

Comment: @oerkelens probably I din' get it then! I took it this way - I was in grave need of your help. *Thank god, I found you!* A scarred girl talking to a policeman. And in *missing context,* - The FBI has put a reward of USD 1 mn. on you, yipee...I found you! :P

Comment: Yes, _I found you_ comes from the verb _find_, _nice to found you_ comes from the verb _found_. _Nice to have found you_ comes from _find_ again.

Answer (score 2):

There are very specific phrases which *glad* features in, where other words are less fitting.  For instance:

> "I'm glad you enjoyed it."

But *"I'm glad to meet you."* is--at least--in American English, a bit awkward.  *"Nice to meet you."* or *"Pleased to meet you."* or even simply *"A pleasure." (wink)* sound less stilted.

Trying to reverse-engineer a rule for why...I think that "glad" tends to feature more in a sense of expressing *relief*.  It's as if there was a bad outcome to be compared to.

> "I'm glad you got here in time!"

In fact, the marketing campaign for [Glad trashbags](http://www.glad.com) has used contrast explicitly in their marketing.  A poor quality trashbag would collapse, while a Glad trashbag would not, so they say *"Don't get mad, get Glad(tm)."*

This would draw a subtle difference between *"I'm glad I met you."* (because of some good outcome that wouldn't have happend vs. not having met you), as opposed to this *"Glad to meet you."* which isn't really clear what you'd be sad/mad about.